# How delete a pair from a list of pairs if the last element of the pair is complex?

Tags: list-manipulation, complex, filtering

Suppose we have a list of pairs for example $\{\{1,2\},\{-1,2+3i\},\{4,6i\},\{3,4\}\}$

How delete the pairs from a list of pairs if the last element of the pair is complex?

Such that in the above case the second and third elements get removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```
DeleteCases[{{1, 2}, {-1, 2 + 3 I}, {4, 6 I}, {3, 4}}, {_, _Complex}]
(* {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} *)
```

For the other cases you can use pattern, built-in functions or user-functions.
For example, try to delete elements with negative numbers in the second place

```
data = {{1, 2}, {-1, -3}, {4, 6}, {3, -4}}; 
DeleteCases[data, {_, _?((# < 0)&)}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {-1, 2 + 3 I}, {4, 6 I}, {3, 4}};
```

Using `RealValuedNumberQ` (new in 13.3)

```
Cases[list, {__?RealValuedNumberQ}]
```

{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

Using `Pick` and `FreeQ`

```
Pick[list, FreeQ[_Complex] /@ list]
```

{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

Answer (score 1):

Another variant using `Pick` and `ReIm`:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {-1, 2 + 3 I}, {4, 6 I}, {3, 4}};

Pick[#, AllTrue[#, Last@ReIm[#] == 0 &] & /@ #] &@list

(*{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}*)
```

Or using `Select` and `RealValuedNumberQ`:

```
Select[list, MatchQ[Total@#, _?RealValuedNumberQ] &]

(* (*{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}*)*)
```

Or using `Delete` and `Position`:

```
Delete[#, Position[{a_, b_Complex}]@#] &@list

(* (*{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}*)*)
```